# intializer not complete normally

Tags: java

I have code like this from Github. and when I compile I get an error at 1 segment - it said initializer cannot complete normally.

```
class Z
{
    private static final String a;
    
    public static String toHex(final byte[] array) {
        final boolean b = Order.b;
        String str = "";
        final int length = array.length;
        int i = 0;
        final boolean b2 = b;
        String string = null;
        while (i < length) {
            string = str + K.a(String.format(Z.a, array[i]), 2, '0') + " ";
            if (b2) {
                return string;
            }
            str = string;
            ++i;
            if (b2) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return string;
    }
    
    public static String toAscii(final byte[] array) {
        final boolean b = Order.b;
        String s = "";
        final boolean b2 = b;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < array.length) {
            Label_0067: {
                if (array[i] == 0) {
                    s += " ";
                    if (!b2) {
                        break Label_0067;
                    }
                }
                s += (char)array[i];
            }
            ++i;
            if (b2) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
    
    static {
        final char[] charArray = "\u001b\u0010".toCharArray();
        int length;
        int n2;
        final int n = n2 = (length = charArray.length);
        int n3 = 0;
        while (true) {
            Label_0119: {
                if (n > 1) {
                    break Label_0119;
                }
                length = (n2 = n3);
                do {
                    final char c = charArray[n2];
                    char c2 = '\0';
                    switch (n3 % 7) {
                        case 0: {
                            c2 = '>';
                            break;
                        }
                        case 1: {
                            c2 = 'H';
                            break;
                        }
                        case 2: {
                            c2 = 'Z';
                            break;
                        }
                        case 3: {
                            c2 = '3';
                            break;
                        }
                        case 4: {
                            c2 = '\u001d';
                            break;
                        }
                        case 5: {
                            c2 = '\u0005';
                            break;
                        }
                        default: {
                            c2 = '6';
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    charArray[length] = (char)(c ^ c2);
                    ++n3;
                } while (n == 0);
            }
            if (n <= n3) {
                a = new String(charArray).intern();
                return;
            }
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

but in this segment, I get the error:

> intializer not complete normally

and cannot return within initializer.

```
static {
        final char[] charArray = "\u001b\u0010".toCharArray();
        int length;
        int n2;
        final int n = n2 = (length = charArray.length);
        int n3 = 0;
        while (true) {
            Label_0119: {
                if (n > 1) {
                    break Label_0119;
                }
                length = (n2 = n3);
                do {
                    final char c = charArray[n2];
                    char c2 = '\0';
                    switch (n3 % 7) {
                        case 0: {
                            c2 = '>';
                            break;
                        }
                        case 1: {
                            c2 = 'H';
                            break;
                        }
                        case 2: {
                            c2 = 'Z';
                            break;
                        }
                        case 3: {
                            c2 = '3';
                            break;
                        }
                        case 4: {
                            c2 = '\u001d';
                            break;
                        }
                        case 5: {
                            c2 = '\u0005';
                            break;
                        }
                        default: {
                            c2 = '6';
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    charArray[length] = (char)(c ^ c2);
                    ++n3;
                } while (n == 0);
            }
            if (n <= n3) {
                a = new String(charArray).intern();
                return;
            }
            continue;
        }
```

Do you have any idea what is going on, please? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you extract the code in your `static` initializer into a `static` method that you call in the initializer, your code will compile.

```
static {
    runMethod();
}

private static void runMethod() {
    final char[] charArray = "\u001b\u0010".toCharArray();
    int length;
    int n2;
    final int n = n2 = (length = charArray.length);
    int n3 = 0;
    while (true) {
        Label_0119: {
            if (n > 1) {
                break Label_0119;
            }
            length = (n2 = n3);
            do {
                final char c = charArray[n2];
                char c2 = '\0';
                switch (n3 % 7) {
                case 0: {
                    c2 = '>';
                    break;
                }
                case 1: {
                    c2 = 'H';
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    c2 = 'Z';
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    c2 = '3';
                    break;
                }
                case 4: {
                    c2 = '\u001d';
                    break;
                }
                case 5: {
                    c2 = '\u0005';
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    c2 = '6';
                    break;
                }
                }
                charArray[length] = (char) (c ^ c2);
                ++n3;
            } while (n == 0);
        }
        if (n <= n3) {
            a = new String(charArray).intern();
            return;
        }
        continue;
    }
}
```